# Duplicate identifier 'nodeName' in jquery.d.ts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have referenced jquery.d.ts in my TypeScript Project in Visual Studio 2012 and am getting the following error:

> Error 1   Duplicate identifier
>   'nodeName'    C:\DEV\MyProject\Scripts\JQuery\jquery.d.ts 786 2   pageMain.ts

Which leads to the following code in jquery.d.ts:

```
interface EventTarget {
    nodeName: string;
}
```

I have restarted VS2012, and then again after deleting all the .sou files for the project.

I have checked all my references (includes) and found no other reference to EventTarget.

I have looked in lib.d.ts, and indeed, there is a EventTarget interface, but it does not implement nodeName.

FYI: I found two copies of lib.d.ts on my machine, and checked them both: does anyone know which one is used by the compiler?  I did mods on both (changing the window.alert to window.alert2), but they had no effect.

Comment: From where get the jquery.d.ts file. I feel you have the wrong file, please get it from http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/258e00903a9e#typings/jquery.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery.d.ts needs to be updated.

Here is a quick way to test the issue:

```
declare var x: EventTarget;
x.nodeName = '';
```

If you run this on the TypeScript Playground, you'll see that `nodeName` does not exist on `EventTarget`. Indeed, if you look at the lib.d.ts file, you'll find this:

```
interface EventTarget {
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListener, useCapture?: bool): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListener, useCapture?: bool): void;
    dispatchEvent(evt: Event): bool;
}
```

However, if you run the same code within Visual Studio with Web Essentials, you'll find that `nodeName` *does* exist on EventTarget. This is because Web Essentials is using a newer version of lib.d.ts - if you disable Web Essentials, you would get the same error as you see in the Playground.

These issues will happen occasionally as the standard definitions are improved to keep up with what browsers actually support. Your definition files should be adjusted to keep in line with your development tools, with a preference to changing files such as jquery.d.ts rather than lib.d.ts.

Comment: How can this be the issue if I do not see EventTarget.nodeName in the lib.d.ts file?  Is the compiler using some type of hidden lib.d.ts file?  If not, where is it located?

Comment: Web Essentials must be using its own version of `lib.d.ts`. You can test this for yourself by disabling Web Essentials and re-starting Visual Studio - you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bug, I faced same issue with className instead of nodeName

After spending sometime trying to solve the issue I found this article link in jquery.d.ts file

I am maintaining general.d.ts file to create required interface items needed.
I added the following definition to the file

```
     interface EventTarget {
         className: string;
    }
```

Immediately I got an error message of duplicate identifier.
I kept it and saved general.d.ts, and went back to my original working file, I found the compiler passed through.
My assumption it is Web Essentials bug failing to load definitions properly.